# When to prefix attribute name with $ in Mongo db aggregate function.?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

```
db.SHIPMENT.aggregate([{$match:{'WNAME':'R group'}},
{$lookup:{"from":"PART","localField":"PNO","foreignField":"PNO","as":"parts"}},
{$unwind:"$parts"},
{$project:{"PARTS":"$parts","_id":0}}])

db.SHIPMENT.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":"$WNAME",total:{"$sum":"$QUANTITY"}}}])
```

full code: https://github.com/VikasNS/RIT-5th-sem-DBMS/blob/master/A42.js

1. In the aggregate function:

   {$match:{'WNAME':'R group'}

In this WNAME does have prefix of $

But

```
{$unwind:"$parts"},
```

parts has a $ in its prefix.

2 nd query

```
total:{"$sum":"$QUANTITY"}}
```

QUANTITY HAS A $ prefix.

So, When to have $ prefix and when not to.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$` prefix whenever you're providing a field name as the *value* in an object (i.e. to the right of the colon).

The exception being where the field can only be the name of a field, as in the `localField` and `foreignField` fields of a `$lookup` object.

Comment: But in lookup we are not prefixing with $?

Comment: Good point! I guess the exception being where the field must be the name of field, eliminating any potential ambiguity. I updated the answer.